# Removing Title from the actionbar in Android 3.0

Tags: java, android

I have a requirement in which I have to make an application that works from Android 3.0 onwards. Naturally I didnt go for ActionBarSherlock.

Now I replaced the background of the actionbar using the following code from the official google resource .

```
<resources>
 <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
       parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
       parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/navigation_bar</item>

</style>
```

As a result , I now have the proper action bar .
[image]

Now the problem is , when I press the home icon ( ic_launcher.png) , when the icon is in pressed state I see the activity title and a carrot sign appear . I do not want such. I just want the home button to be clickable and would like to see nothing while the button is pressed .

I did succeed in removing the activity title that appears by using

```
getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

however the default "<" sign still appears when the home icon is pressed .

Question 1 : How can I remove the "<" sign when the home icon is in pressed state
Question 2 : How can I remove the default options icon (on the right side , the three dots) ?

Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

For  home Icon remove

```
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.color.transfrant);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the title bar
in manifest under the activity

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
```

Change the action bar name. Android manifest under the activity

```
android:label="@string/app_name"
```

change to

```
android:label=" "
```

Comment: thanks . Also as I asked in the question , do you have any idea how would I remove the three dots in the corner ? . The one which invokes the option menu

Comment: i couldn't see that any dots in my application. please explain.

Answer (score 0):

`Question 2 : How can I remove the default options icon (on the right side , the three dots) ?`

remove this method from your Activity class

```
 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
 }
```